# std::binding a template function

Tags: c++11

I have a function that is part of a class handles some input as pair of iterators. The signature of which is:

```
class Obj {
public:
    template <typename InputIterator>
    void handle_read(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
...
};
```

I would like to bind that to a function:

```
void Obj::handle_connect() {
    connections.start(std::make_shared<connection>(std::move(socket), connections, logger),
        std::bind(&server::handle_read<InputIterator>, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

However that doesn't work, specifically the error suggests that it can't find InputIterator.

However if I put the exact signature for the bind in:

```
        std::bind(&server::handle_read<std::array<uint8_t, 8192>::iterator>, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

It compiles, but the code is brittle: If I change to a vector then I will need to go around changing the signatures (though failing code will be easy to detect), and if I decide that a different container would be more efficient than an array in a particular use case, then it breaks altogether.

How I do keep the bind generic and not tied to a particular iterator type?

Comment: In `Obj::handle_connect` what is `InputIterator`? Where is it defined for the `handle_connect` function? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Giving a MCVE while nice I would have to have main, the server class, the connection manager class, the connection class itself, plus the code for the parser that returns the two iterators when I am looking for how to bind a template member function.  I thought the name `InputIterator` would suggest what it is especially when I show that it is of type `std::array<uint8_t, 8192>::iterator` a few lines later.

Comment: What I mean, is `Obj::handle_connect` a template? Is it declared such as `template<typename InputIterator> void handle_connect();`? If not, how do you think that it should know about the symbol `InputIterator`? As far as we can see it's only defined for the `handle_read` function.

Comment: `handle_connect` is not a template.  That is what I am asking: How to deduce what the type of the iterator is?  `handle_connect` has no idea of what the iterators would be after parsing - why would it?  So how can I bind a templated member function?

Comment: You simply can't use a generic `InputIterator` symbol without any kind of definition. If the function doesn't know about it then it doesn't know about it. Perhaps it's less a code-issue and more of a design-issue?

Comment: Probably is a design issue. It seemed like a good idea at the time to return data as a pair of iterators after performing basic sanitation checks.

Comment: Introduce a typedef for `std::array<uint8_t, 8192>` and/or `std::array<uint8_t, 8192>::iterator` somewhere (perhaps in whatever class `socket` is an instance of), and use that typedef to instantiate `handle_read`. This way, you are free to change this typedef to `vector` later.